# How to use Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform in my applications/projects

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

So I have a bunch of older .net apps and projects that target .net 4.5.1, none of which have the Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform nuget package installed. I use the latest and greatest VS 2017, so I get the latest c# features on my dev machine. However our TFS build server doesn't always stay up to date with the tooling we use on our dev machines, so for instance c# 7 features work locally on my dev machine, but not on the build server. That's what I'm working with, but I have some questions about how that nuget package can/should be used in my projects:

1. Will adding the latest
   Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform package to my app
   allow my build server to compile the newer c# features?
2. How is the Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform
   package used? Is it something that the build-time compiler uses? I
   read somewhere that it would improve the startup time of my asp.net
   app if I have it installed on my web app project.
3. What projects need to have the Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform package installed? Does it need to be added to every project that I want to use c# 7 features in?